# Selenium driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;") returns 0 even though it's not 0

Tags: python, selenium

The following command:

```
print("!!!:" + str(driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")))
```

gives back 0 in python console

js-console in browser tells me `window.pageYOffset; 1597`

Am  I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

check if you got the right active window
if not you can switch with these commands

```
 a = driver.window_handles[i]
    driver.switch_to.window(a)
```

i would be the index of your tab/window